# oozie sqoop optionsfile gives File Not Found exception

Tags: oozie, hue, hortonworks-data-platform

I have the various blogs about mentioning about the fact that the options file required for the Sqoop job should be placed inside the HDFS location.

I did place the file in the HDFS location and provided the file in the file argument as well.

Despite this, it throws the FileNotFound exception.

The oozie workflow file is shown as below -

```
    <workflow-app name="TestFlow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
        <start to="TableImport"/>
        <action name="TableImport">
            <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                <prepare>
                      <delete path="${nameNode}/path/to/place/file"/>
                </prepare>
                  <arg>--options-file </arg>
                  <arg>/tmp/sqoopoptions.params</arg>
                  <arg>--target-dir</arg>
                  <arg>/path/to/place/file</arg>
                  <arg>--query</arg>
                  <arg>select employee_id, employeename, DEPT_ID from employee where $CONDITIONS</arg>
                  <arg>--split-by</arg>
                  <arg>DEPT_ID</arg>
               <file>/tmp/sqoopoptions.params#sqoopoptions.params</file>
            </sqoop>
            <ok to="end"/>
            <error to="kill"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="kill">
            <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end"/>
    </workflow-app>
```

The options file is present in the HDFS location

```
/tmp/sqoopoptions.params
```

I can view the file from Hue, means that the file is in HDFS location!.

Im using Hortonworks 2.1 distribution

The exception stakctrace is

```
    4046 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Error while expanding arguments
    java.lang.Exception: Unable to read options file: /tmp/sqoopoptions.params
        at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:102)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:33)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:203)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:206)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:174)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/sqoopoptions.params (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:70)
```

Update:

I tried to place the options file in the local file system where oozie server is running. It works. When I looked at the code, it also seems correct. The relevant section from org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil is shown below

```
     public static String[] expandArguments(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          if (args[i].equals(Sqoop.SQOOP_OPTIONS_FILE_SPECIFIER)) {
            if (i == args.length - 1) {
              throw new Exception("Missing options file");
            }

            String fileName = args[++i];
            File optionsFile = new File(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            try {
             **reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(optionsFile));**
              String nextLine = null;
              while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Now, this works with the local file configuration. It means that, if I place the file in HDFS, it wont work. Unless, FileReader will pick the file from the HDFS location if the path is given as hdfs://namdnode/path/to/file . Is this how it is expected to work?

I gave the parameter to {nameNode}/tmp/sqoopoptions.params. It throws the following exception. If I notice it closely, the / is causing an issue. Its clear from the exception stack trace. One of the slash disappears while passing to the FileReader

```
    java.lang.Exception: Unable to read options file: hdfs://ipofnamednode:port/tmp/sqoopoptions.params
        at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:102)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:33)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:203)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:206)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:174)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
    **Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/ipofnamednode:port/tmp/sqoopoptions.params (No such file or directory)**
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:70)
        ... 21 more
```

As seen in the stacktrace, one of the slash is removed due to escape characters.

Comment: Did you create /tmp/sqoopoptions.params from Hue? In old version it can be corrupted. Could you try to create the file on the CLI then upload it?

Comment: @Romain: I created the file via CLI and uploaded and still the problem did not resolve. But I have an update, since it involves code, added it in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your file path in the `<file>` property with the namenode, so for example:

```
<file>hdfs://tmp/sqoopoptions.params#sqoopoptions.params</file>
```

Comment: Tried the same but it did not work as well. Seems to be an issue and update provided in the main question itself.

Comment: Try without the port?

Comment: yes, if i give {namenode} in the workflow xml, the same will be replaced. In short, port is present

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving the symlink name as the `<arg>` and adding namenode to the start of the `<file>` tag :

```
    ...
    <arg>--options-file </arg>
    <arg>sqoopoptions.params</arg>
    ...
    <file>${namenode}/tmp/sqoopoptions.params#sqoopoptions.params</file>
    ...
```